# add another value to scheduler description

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, scheduler

iam using scheduler control from devexpress. what i want to ask is how do i add another value to scheduler mapping description.

the code i use

```
            schedulerStorage1.Resources.DataSource = dt;
            schedulerControl1.Storage.Resources.DataSource = dt;
            schedulerStorage1.Appointments.DataSource = dt;

            schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.Start = dt.Columns["Start"].ToString();
            schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.End = dt.Columns["End"].ToString();
            schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.Subject = dt.Columns["Title"].ToString();
            schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.Description = dt.Columns["description"].ToString();
```

the display is like this

[image]

from there i want to add another value to mapping description, iam using this code

```
          schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.Description = dt.Columns["description"].ToString() + dt.Columns["name"].ToString();
```

but the element of description is not showing anything

[image]

Comment: are you sure the "name" column is present in the DataSource and that it doesn't throw an exception when you try to reference it? Run your code in the debugger and see if there are any exceptions.

Comment: yes, iam pretty sure, i also change the column "name" to "title" itself didnt show up anything

Comment: when debug was smooth, didnt give anything error

Answer (score 0):

i have solve it by this.

first i need to add a new custom mapping

```
     this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.CustomFieldMappings.Add(new AppointmentCustomFieldMapping("a", dt.Columns["name"].ToString()));
```

and then i need to assign it `schedulerControl1_InitAppointmentDisplayText` the code i use is

```
   private void schedulerControl1_InitAppointmentDisplayText(object sender, AppointmentDisplayTextEventArgs e)
    {                   
     e.Description = e.ViewInfo.Appointment.Description + e.ViewInfo.Appointment.CustomFields["a"].ToString();            
    }
```